# UserForm to change text to uppercase, lowercase or using proper function

Tags: vba, excel

guys!

At this time I created an UserForm to change the letters on my text using three options:

1. Uppercase
2. Lowercase
3. Proper Function

My first code used the If-Then structure and it was ok. I put it below:

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Dim WorkRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

'Detects only constant type (text; excludes formulas)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRange = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlCellTypeConstants)

'Uppercase
    If OptionUpper Then
        For Each cell In WorkRange
            cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    End If

'Uppercase
    If OptionLower Then
        For Each cell In WorkRange
            cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)
        Next cell
    End If

'Using Proper Function
    If OptionProper Then
        For Each cell In WorkRange
            cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
        Next cell
    End If
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

I used a mode to run the UserForm1:

```
Sub ChangeCase2()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        UserForm1.Show
    Else
        MsgBox "Selection a range.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

And all worked fine. But then I thought: Could it be possible to use Select Case structure? So I tried and unfortunately, didn´t run. The uppercase option works as lowercase while the Lowercase and Proper are working as Uppercase. I reviewed the captions that I gave to the buttons and it´s all fine. Could sb help me, please?

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Unload UserForm2 
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Dim WorkRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim OptionSelect As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRange = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlCellTypeConstants)

    Select Case OptionSelect
        Case OptionUpper 'Letras Maiúsculas
            For Each cell In WorkRange
                cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
            Next cell
        Case OptionLower 'Letras Minúsculas
            For Each cell In WorkRange
                cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)
            Next cell
        Case OptionProper 'Iniciais Maiúsculas
            For Each cell In WorkRange
                cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
            Next cell
    End Select
    Unload UserForm2
End Sub
```

I used another mode to UserForm2:

```
Sub ChangeCase3()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        UserForm2.Show
    Else
        MsgBox "Selection a range.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you think `OptionSelect` will get assigned `OptionUpper`, `OptionLower` or `OptionProper`? Do you think that value just magically appears because you added the line `Dim OptionSelect As Variant`?

Comment: As it seems it was a silly mistake. I am newbie on VBA, but I still appreciate your commment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
Select Case OptionSelect
```

use

```
Select Case True
```

this will give you the proper value to match OptionButtons Values against

Comment: Thanks a lot! But a still have a question: why on this microsoft example the Case Select True was not used? I follow that example and thought that my variable Option Select would receive the options of Case Select. I know I probably make some kind of mistake but I am struggling to identify it.

Comment: Should I erase the line Dim OptionSelect As Variant beacuse it was unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

The first code takes the value for `OptionSelect` from somewhere.

If it worked there, then the problem is that in your second code you have this extra line:

```
Dim OptionSelect As Variant
```

On this line you make this value empty, so it will make the `Select Case` useless as there is no value.